# draw a vertical line in a custom dialog

Tags: wix

there is a way to draw horizontal line < control **type="Line"**... **Width="370" Height="2"** />. however it doesn't allow me to draw a vertical line with < control **type="Line"**... **Width="2" Height="100"** />. why???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of the Windows Installer.  The Line control can only describe be a horizontal line.  The Height attribute is ignored.  This is probably also a WiX defect in that the compiler should give an error when trying to provide a Height Attribute when the Type is Line.

[Line Control (Windows Installer -MSDN )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369760(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: well, newer wix should fix this issue :/

Comment: WiX is a toolset built on top of Windows Installer. It can't fix the problems of underlying technology - just tries to make them less annoying...

Comment: No, but WiX could do a better job of validating the XML and break with an error explaining the windows installer limitation.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use bitmap - 1x1 pixel, black. Something like

```
<Control Id="VerticalLine" Type="Bitmap" X="120" Y="10" Width="1" Height="230" Text="WixUI_Bmp_Black"/>
```